# Делегат для всех функций

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Привет!
Недавно начал изучать делегаты и решил попробовать их на практике, написал метод для вычисления среднего времени выполнения метода:

```
public delegate void
     FunctionDelegate();

static public long SpeedTest(FunctionDelegate del, 
     int numberIterations)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    var listValue = new List<long>();

    for (var index = 0; index < numberIterations; index++)
    {
        stopWatch.Restart();

        del();

        stopWatch.Stop();
        listValue.Add(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    return listValue.Sum() / listValue.Count;
}
```

И возник вопрос, а можно ли сделать такой делегат, чтобы в него можно было любой метод засунуть, да еще и потом любые параметры передать?

Что-то вроде этого:

```
public delegate Object FunctionDelegate(params object[] args);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет. Вы неправильно подходите, вам стоит подумать в сторону генериков.

Написать делегат, принимающий произвольное количество аргументов, и вовсе невозможно. Причина простая: если бы такое было возможно, и в этот делегат записывается функция, принимающая, скажем, 1 параметр, как компилятор удостоверится, что вы не сможете её вызвать с двумя параметрами?

В .NET нет функций, принимающих произвольное количество параметров. Функция

```
void test(params object[] p) { /* ... */ }
```

принимает **один** параметр, а список объектов в массив для вас превращает заботливый компилятор.

Что вам на самом деле стоит сделать, так это обернуть произвольную функцию в лямбду:

```
static public double SpeedTest(Action a, int numberIterations)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    var listValue = new List<double>();

    for (var index = 0; index < numberIterations; index++)
    {
        stopWatch.Restart();
        a();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        listValue.Add(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    return listValue.Average();
}

double f (double x, double y) { return Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y); }

double x = 1, y = 1;
var averageSpeed = SpeedTest(() =>
    {
        var z = f(x, y);
        x = y;
        y = z;
    }, 10000);
```